# I have sql query - i want to convert to OLEDB query:

Tags: .net, sql-server, excel, t-sql, oledb

I have a table in below given format:

```
ID  NARR3

1   One
2   Two
1   One
2   Four
2   Five
```

I need output like this:

```
 ID NARR3

 1  One
 2  Five,Four,Two
```

I tried following SQL server query and it works fine.

```
select
t1.[ID],
 STUFF((select ',' + st.[NARR3]
        from (select Distinct(t.[NARR3]) from [IMMS$] t
        where t.[ID] = t1.[ID]) st       
        for xml path 
 )1,1,'') as [NARR3]

from [IMMS] t1
group by [ID]
```

But i want this to work with OLEDB connection. When I try to run with OLEDB connection, i get following error:

```
Syntax error in query expression 'STUFF((select ',' + st.[NARR3] from (select Distinct(t.[NARR3]) from [IMMS] t where t.[ID] = t1.[ID]) st for xml path),1,1,'')'.
```

The dotnet code that i am using is as below:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
using (Command com = new Command(connection, query, st, 0))
{
    dt = com.PopulateDataTable(dt);
    dt.TableName = tablename;
}
return dt;

where 
connection = Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\IMMS SHEET FILLED WITH DETAILS1.xlsx;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 XML;IMEX=1;HDR=YES';
tableName = Table1
query = Above query
st = OLEDB
```

And PopulateDataTable function is as follows:

```
public DataTable PopulateDataTable(DataTable dt)
{
   _connection.Open();
   using (_adapter)
   {
       _adapter.Fill(dt);enter code here
   }    
   _connection.Close();//conn
   return dt;
}
```

Help will be highly appreciable. I don't know what I am missing in OLEDB query.

Comment: Can you show us the definition of your OLEDB query? I'm guessing it has something to do with the quotes in the command somehow being understood as the beginning or ending of the query.

Comment: I have not made any query, i am just running the above query into OLEDB connection, but this throws error.

Comment: What do you mean by OleDB Connection? Where are you executing this?

Comment: In DOTNET application.

Comment: So show us the code?

Comment: In terms of your comments to my deleted answer, you really need to write where you are using this and in which way. You have to show the code else its pure guessing

Comment: If you are retrieving data from excel, i would stage it as it is. And then do the magic afterwards.

Comment: Please show us the exact code where the query is defined within your code. That is most likely where your issue comes from.

Comment: As i wrote to you before. EXCEL most likely doesnt know stuff function etc. Extract your data in the simplest form by SELECT * FROM [IMMS$] - Add this to your DataTable. Bulk copy it to a table on your SQL Server, and then do your stuff/group concat magic.